# Python: accessing attributes and methods of one class in another

Tags: python, oop

Let's say I have two classes A and B:

```
Class A:
   # A's attributes and methods here

Class B:
  # B's attributes and methods here
```

Now I can assess A's properties in object of B class as follows:

```
a_obj = A()
b_obj = B(a_obj)
```

What I need is a two way access.
How do I access A's properties in B and B's properties in A ?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to access a_obj's members in b_obj's?  Or do you just want the classes to have properties with the same names?

Comment: i want to access each objects properties from within the other (mutual access) and Martjin's answer lets me do that :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to create pointers either way:

```
class A(object):
    parent = None


class B(object):
    def __init__(self, child):
        self.child = child
        child.parent = self
```

Now `A` can refer to `self.parent` (provided it is not `None`), and `B` can refer to `self.child`. If you try to make an instance of `A` the child of more than one `B`, the last 'parent' wins.

Comment: can you please elaborate a little more on how you instantiate objects out of the two.

Comment: I used *your* example at the end, actually.

Comment: What if the `class A` also using `__init__` that has attribute in it? How do we can access it from `class B`?

Comment: @xkderhaka: you mean that `A` has more attributes? Then just use `self.child.<attribute>`.

Answer (score 5):

Why not just plan your objects in a way where this can be taken care of with inheritance.

```
class A(object):
    # stuff

class B(A):
    # has A methods/properties

class C(B):
    # has A and B methods/properties
```

In this case by planing ahead, you could just use `C` for a generalist object, and `A` with `B` as more specialised/bare parents.

Comment: very  insightful .. but have come too far in my current program to afford a class restructure. Lesson learned for future :)

Comment: This is a very bare bones example of inheritance, I would urge you to Google the hell out of this topic :). Inheritance is like the main feature of OOP languages such as Python. Good luck @QuakiGabbar!

Comment: @MorganWilde : Who's 'QuakiGabbar' ?

Answer (score 3):

This method will be very useful, as you can use objects of both the classes interchangeably. There is a serious problem with this, I ll explain that at the end.

```
class A:
    def MethodA(self):
        return "Inside MethodA"

    def __init__ (self, Friend=None):
        self.__dict__['a'] = "I am a"
        self.__dict__['Friend'] = Friend
        if Friend is not None: self.__dict__['Friend'].__dict__['Friend'] = self

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if self.Friend is not None: return getattr(self.Friend, name)
        raise AttributeError ("Unknown Attribute `" + name + "`")

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if self.Friend is not None: setattr(self.Friend, name, value)
        raise AttributeError ("Unknown Attribute `" + name + "`")

class B:
    def MethodB(self):
        return "Inside MethodB"

    def __init__ (self, Friend=None):
        self.__dict__['b'] = "I am b"
        self.__dict__['Friend'] = Friend
        if Friend is not None: self.__dict__['Friend'].__dict__['Friend'] = self

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if self.Friend is not None: return getattr(self.Friend, name)
        raise AttributeError ("Unknown Attribute `" + name + "`")

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if self.Friend is not None: setattr(self.Friend, name, value)
        raise AttributeError ("Unknown Attribute `" + name + "`")
```

**Explanation:**

As per [this page](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-attribute-access), `__getattr__` and `__setattr__` will be invoked on python objects only when the requested attribute is not found in the particular object's space. So in the constructor we are establishing relationship between both the classes. And then whenever `__getattr__` or `__setattr__` is called, we refer the other object using `getattr` method. ([getattr](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr), [setattr](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr)) We use `__dict__` to assign values in the constructor, so that we ll not call `__setattr__` or `__getattr__`.

**Sample Runs:**

```
b = B()
# print b.a    # Throws AttributeError, as A and B are not related yet
a = A(b)

print a.a
print a.b
print b.a      # Works fine here, as 'a' is not found b, returns A's a
print b.b

print a.MethodA()
print a.MethodB()
print b.MethodA()
print b.MethodB()

I am a
I am b
I am a
I am b
Inside MethodA
Inside MethodB
Inside MethodA
Inside MethodB
```

**Now, the serious problem:**

If we try to access an attribute which is not there in both these objects, we ll end up in infinite recursion. Lets say I want to access 'C' from 'a'. Since C is not in a, it will call `__getattr__` and it will refer b object. As b object doesnt have C, it  will call `__getattr__` which will refer object a. So we end up in an infinite recursion. So this approach works fine, when you you don't access anything unknown to both the objects.

Comment: Why duplicate the declaration of identical methods for both `A` and `B`, I.e. the getter and setter? I feel this technique is missing all the benefits of polymorphism, still +1 for the effort.

Comment: @MorganWilde The OP couldn't afford polymorphism. He mentioned that in one of the comments :( Thanks for the upvote :)