# Accessing attributes and methods of one class in another. Continue of previous thread

Tags: python, oop

I found this thread where one person was asking about ["Python: accessing attributes and methods of one class in another"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17383716/9445557)

[And one answer of Martijn Pieters♦](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17383736/9445557) was next:

```
class A(object):
    parent = None


class B(object):
    def __init__(self, child):
        self.child = child
        child.parent = self
```

"Now A can refer to self.parent (provided it is not None), and B can refer to self.child. If you try to make an instance of A the child of more than one B, the last 'parent' wins."

Unfortunately, I can't comment because of lack of privileges, so I've decided to ask, as soon as I understand this, if it's too stupid to ask, I will delete this thread, but before that...

I've been seating on these line one day, and I still don't get it, so for example, I have this situation:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master=master
        self.b=B()


    def meth1(self):
        self.b.meth2()



class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def meth2():
        #some method


root=Tk()
a=A(root)
```

In this case, I start with class A, from within that class I create an instance of class B, pass there some data, do some calculations there, now, to finish my calculations I need to get some values from the class A, how can I reach it from the class B?
I mean, I know I can create some instance of class B form the main function, but it will get more confusing I guess...
Again, if I'm missing here something, I would appreciate you guys to help me.

Comment: if you need a link from an instance of class B to an instance of class A, you could add a `parent` parameter in B constructor to store the reference in self.parent, then you can pass the reference of A when you instantiate B : `self.b=B(self)`.

Comment: @PRMoureu FINALLY.... Thank you good man! I get it! Now everything is making sense...